# How do i init dictionary with range of keys in swift?

Tags: swift

Here is a swift dictionary declaration:

```
var cardField = [Int:Card]()
```

How can i init a keys for this dictionary, using range syntax? 
Something like that:

```
var cardField: [Int:Card] = [0...5:nil]
```

This is doesn't work...
Thank you.

Comment: What values should be associated with each of those keys?

Comment: Let it be String values. No matter.

Comment: Of course i could use loop statement to add an Int keys, but... Is there more efficient way?

Comment: The values matter. Your question indicates some custom class/struct of `Card`. Even if it is `String`, do you want unique strings for each key or the same string for each key? Please [edit] your question and clearly define your requirements. Vague questions with vague requirements are harder to answer well.

Comment: I’d like to init keys with nil values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Range` isn't a `Sequence`, so it can't be directly passed to `reduce(into:)`  `stride` is though, so you can use something like:

```
let cardField = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: stride(from: 0, to: 5, by: 1).map { ($0, "\($0)" )})
```

The biggest problem is you haven't specified what the value of the keys should be, so without that information we're really just poking in the dark.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array then add it to a dictionary:

```
var values = Array(1...5)
let keyToValue = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(values, 1...5))
print(keyToValue[3]!)
// Prints 3
print(keyToValue)
// Prints [5: 5, 2: 2, 3: 3, 1: 1, 4: 4]
```